# Microsoft Edge Browser isn't opening on selenium grid

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-grid, selenium-edgedriver

I need to launch Microsoft edge browser through selenium grid, but whenever I try to launch the browser below error thrown and browser is not initiated

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z' System info: host: 'ERD-L046', ip: '192.168.2.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info: driver.version: unknown Command duration or timeout: 74 milliseconds
```

To configure a grid set up I have used the below code : 
To set up HUB :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role hub
```

To set up Node :

```
java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="D:/Softwares/Selenium/IEDriver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -port 5567 -role node -hub http://192.168.2.46:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=MicrosoftEdge, maxInstances=5"
```

To launch the browser I have used the below code :

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.setCapability("platform", "Any");
    options.setCapability("browserName", "MicrosoftEdge");
    options.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
    options.setCapability("browserVersion", "41.16299.15.0");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:/Softwares/Selenium/Drivers/IEDriver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.2.46:5567/wd/hub"), options);
```

OS : Windows 10 pro [version 1709 16299.125]

Browser version : 41.16299.15.0

Selenium Version : 3.13.0

Selenium server standalone : 3.13.0

Microsoft WebDriver version : Release 16299 | Version: 5.16299 | Edge version supported: 16.16299

Kindly someone shed light on this.

Comment: have you tried updating your driver?

Comment: which driver? L_Church , as of now am using lastest version of all which i have mentioned.

Comment: edge latest is 17xxx

Comment: Yes, on updating edge driver to 17xx, it didn't worked either as my OS version will conflict. @L_Church

Comment: @L_Church Ac according to OP's OS version, Driver version is correct.

Comment: @Dhuruvan Please recheck on Driver calling path calling, In mentioned path it includes folder IEDriver. Also you can check with forward double slash.

Comment: @IshitaShah Thank u for pointing out, its working fine, due to invalid location i had faced the issue.

Comment: @Dhuruvan I have added it as answer. Other reader will looking fr answer and usually no one read comments as answer. If you think answer has helped you to solve problem, Please accept it by right clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck on Driver calling path calling, In mentioned path it includes folder IEDriver. Also you can check with forward double slash.